# Equivalent of --keep-locals for LLVM

Tags: assembly, compilation, clang, llvm-clang

Is there any way to keep local assembly symbols using the Clang/LLVM assembler. The GNU one supports a `--keep-locals` (or `-L`) flag, but the LLVM one does not seem to have this option.

Comment: @compor `llvm-as` translates LLVM assembly to LLVM bitcode, but that makes no sense to me in this context. I am pretty much convinced the question is about clang's integrated assembler.

Comment: @hvd oh my bad, I meant to type `llc`. Thanks for that correction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clang may not support the `--keep-locals` long option, but does accept the `-L` short option. Remember that all assembler options must be prefixed with `-Wa,`, so the complete option becomes `-Wa,-L`.

If you are invoking the assembler directly (`clang -cc1as`), then the option is called `-msave-temp-labels`.